# Get onclick information using google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, textbox, onclick

I am doing a web application related to map using google map api v3. Now I have a set of textboxes on the side of the map as shown below. The red ones the user can add as many as he wants refering to waypoints.

[image]

Now I would like to do something similar to google maps where when the user clicks on the map, or a particular point of interest, some data related to the point would be displayed in the textbox of where the cursor will be.

Any ideas how i can accomplish such task?

Comment: This is a problem, not a question. Read:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events and ask questions related to particular task. Via javascript set the onlcik event, gather data from point of interest, perform calculations and add response to your box via javascript

Comment: Click event of the map I know how to do it. What i don't know is how to input data in particuler textbox where the cursor is.

Comment: But how am i going to know in which textbox?

Comment: @IT_info, how can you have the cursor on a textbox when you are clicking on a map. When you click on the map, the cursor will move out of the textbox. You can have radio buttons against the checkbox if you want the user to select a textbox first and then select a point in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Each textbox must have an ID. When your event is triggered, trigger function

```
<script>
var text_to_be_inserted = "sample";
function onEvent(){
    document.getElementById("textbox_1").value='';
    document.getElementById("textbox_2").value='';
    if(document.getElementById("textbox_1").focused){
        document.getElementById("textbox_1").value=text_to_be_inserted;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("textbox_2").focused){
        document.getElementById("textbox_2").value=text_to_be_inserted;
    }
    else{
        // do nothing
    }
}
</script>
```